# is comparison returns False with strings using same id

Tags: python, string, comparison

I was playing around with Python `is` and `==` operator. As far as I know, is operator checks whether two objects have same id, but in my case operator returns False even if two substrings have the same id.

Here is the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
# coding=utf-8
string = "HelloWorld"

print(id(string))    #140131089280176
print(id(string[0:5]))  #140131089251048
print(id(string[-10:-5]))   #140131089251048


print(string[0:5] == string[-10:-5])    #True
print(string[0:5] is string[-10:-5])    #False
```

Substrings do not have same id with the original string as expected, but why is operator returns false with 2 substrings with the same id?

Comment: I'd guess Python is reusing the same slot in memory on the first example, which it can't do when you create two slices at once (or if you assigned them, so they weren't immediately dereferenced).

Answer (score -1):

For me both:

```
print(id(string[0:5]))
print(id(string[-10:-5]))
```

have different IDs, and as such, those answers:

```
print(string[0:5] == string[-10:-5])    #True
print(string[0:5] is string[-10:-5])    #False
```

Are as they should be expected.

Are u sure u didnt make mistake here?

# I would post that as a comment, but cant yet

Comment: I tried again and they both have same id. Both substrings(string[0:5] and string[-10:-5]) should point to the same string literal, "Hello" in this case.